# Getting Simple Objects from Mongoose Objects to Run Underscore's `_.difference()` Method

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, underscore.js

In my MongoDB backend I am using `pre` and `post` hooks to compare pre-save and post-save versions of a document, in order to handle post-processing when certain changes occur. I am also using underscore's `_.difference()` method to find the differences between the two versions of the document.

However, because these are not simple objects, but actually Mongoose objects, there is all sorts of additional data mixed in -- such as:

```
 activePaths: 
 StateMachine {
   paths: [Object],
   states: [Object],
   stateNames: [Array],
   map: [Function] },
pathsToScopes:
```

So, long story short, I'm trying to figure out how to just get the object data - nothing else, so that `_.difference` will pull out the data that's changed. I tried using `JSON.parse()` but this didn't work in my case. I also tried calling the `lean()` Mongoose method on my two docs, but this caused a "not a function" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [toObject()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) method on a document to convert it to a regular object.

The .lean() method can only be called on queries beforehand like this:

```
// passing options (in this case return the raw js objects, not mongoose documents by passing `lean`
Adventure.findById(id, 'name', { lean: true }, function (err, doc) {});

// same as above
Adventure.findById(id, 'name').lean().exec(function (err, doc) {});
```